# Visual Studio Code(vsc) sfdx Command keeps on running

Tags: salesforce-cli

**Summary**
From past few days the SFDX commands are taking way to long to execute, infact I had to cancel them because they are just shown as running for infinite

For Ex: 1.SFDX: Create Project will run infintly,it will create project on system but vsc don't reload/ shows the created project. I observed this for more than 20 min and i have to cancel that.

2.SFDX: Authorize an Org / SFDX: Deploy Source to Org command progress indicator keeps on running.

**Steps To Reproduce:**

**1.** execute sfdx command : SFDX: Create Project used Standard standard project template(default)

**Expected result**
Project should be created and it should open in vsc.

**Actual result**
The command progress indicator keeps on running. It creates Project folder on system but command do not terminate. Not getting 2nd Output on vsc which contains ended with exit code 0.

**2.** execute sfdx command : SFDX: Authorize an Org

**Expected result**
**OUTPUT**
Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org 14:57:12.152 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias gs0Org --setdefaultusername Successfully authorized with org ID You may now close the browser

14:57:45.237 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias gs0Org --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 0

**Actual result**
The command progress indicator keeps on running.
Output: Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org Salesforce CLI 19:15:20.540 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias gs0Org --setdefaultusername Successfully authorized with org ID You may now close the browser

**Not getting this**
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias gs0Org --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 0 And Command keeps on running...

**Additional information:**

VS Code Version: 1.47.3

SFDX CLI Version: sfdx-cli/7.60.0-e2bb2907cb win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

Java Version: 1.8.0_261

System type : 64-bit Operating System,x64-based processor Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Login into your org and go to my domain and uncheck

> Prevent login from https://login.salesforce.com

by this, you'll be able to authenticate your org on VS code.

[image: 1]